# How can I programmatically change the size of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a UICollectionView in the interface builder. I referenced it with

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *contactList;
```

in my .h file and @synthesize contactList; in my .m file.
I tried to implement a slightly different layout in portrait and landscape using the following code:

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)contactList.collectionViewLayout;
        flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(48, 80, 48, 0);
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = 80;
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)contactList.collectionViewLayout;
        flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(48, 64, 48, 0);
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = 64;
    }
}
```

This works prefectly, but I also want to change the size (in landscape I have a 2*3 grid per page and in portrait it's a 3*2 grid). I tried setting the size like this:

```
CGRect frame = [contactList frame];
frame.size.width = 960;
[contactList setFrame:frame];
```

But it won't update. There is no error, but the view just isn't updated. It just stays at the same size as before. What do I have to do to update the view?

Comment: Can you try using `self.contactList`?

Comment: @amar It still doesn't update.

Comment: have you tried automatically setting of size using spring-struts/autolayout?

Comment: @AnuragSoni I use auto-layout for almost anything in my app, but I can't get it right for the size of my collectionview since it shoulnd't really 'snap' to anything or be a certain distance from the edge.

Comment: @AnuragSoni I managed to get auto-layout to do sort of what I want. I think it's enough to get me going, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I always using this:

```
[self.contactList performUpdates:^{
  CGRect frame = [contactList frame];
  frame.size.width = 960;
  [contactList setFrame:frame];

  [self.contactList.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
} completion:nil];
```

This should set your frame and update your layout.

Answer (score -1):

When are you modifying the frame of the `contactList`?  At VC initialization time, outlets are nil.  Your view controller gets a `ViewDidLoad` call after the outlets are connected.

I suspect that `contactList` is still nil when your resizing code is being executed.  Move that code's execution into a `ViewDidLoad` method, and you'll be able to access the real deal.

You can easily test this theory by adding the following to where you resize the frame:

```
NSLog(@"contactList is: %@",contactList.description);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you try to do
`[self.yourcontrollerview reloaddata]`

when you modify the frame..